# Can prefixing a dash reduce the search engine rating?

Tags: url, seo, dash

If I prefix a dash to GUIDs in my URLs on my Web site, in this manner:

```
example.com/some/folders/-35x2ne5r579n32/page-name
```

Will my SEO rating be affected?

***Background:*** On my site, people can look up pages by GUID, and by path.
For example,
both `example.com/forum/-3v32nirn32/eat-animals-without-friends`
and  `example.com/forum/eat-animals-without-friends`
could map to the same page. To indicate that `3v32nirn32` is a GUID and not a page name, I thought I could prefix a `-` and then my webapp would understand.

But I wouldn't want my search engine rating to drop. And prefixing a dash in this manner seems weird, so perhaps Googlebot lowers my rating. Hence my question: Do you know if my search engine rating might drop? (Today or in the future?)

(I could also e.g. prefix `id-`, so the URL becomes `example.com/forum/id-3v32nirn32`, but then people cannot create pages that start with the word "id".)

(I think I don't want URLs like this one: `example.com/id/some-guid`.)

Kind regards, Magnus

Comment: Off topic - belongs on webmasters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That won't affect your rankings. Dashes, and other non alphanumeric characters, are perfect acceptable in URLs and in-and-of themselves do not directly affect rankings.

Comment: Agreed, don't worry about dashes, etc. Additionally: If you have both descriptive & unique text as well as a GUID in the URL, I'd consider dropping the GUID altogether. One URL is enough :-).

Comment: @John Conde: Okay. In my webapp, I've removed the "id-..." code I added a few hours ago and changed to "-..." which I like better :-)

Comment: @John Mueller: I'll use <link rel='canonical'...> to mitigate duplicated contents problems. But it's almost not an issue anyway in my case: Some pages will be accessed almost only via some/path/page-name (e.g. blog and wiki pages), whereas other pages will be accessed exclusively via GUID (e.g. forum pages -- I'd like 2 people to be able to create questions with the same name (but different GUID)).

Comment: @JohnConde Use @ in url, have affect in SEO? (example: `http://www.example.com/@john/post/10`